# bareos Using both tape drives (not multiplexing)

Tags: backup, tapedrive, bareos, autoloader

I'm using a Neoseries T24 (Flexstor II) autoloader with two drives. I have tapes (11 of them) in a pool labeled 'Full'.

When I run two jobs, both for the 'Full' pool, they will wait in sequence so they can both use the same drive (0) instead of one running on drive 0 and one running on drive 1.

Is this because I selected drive 0 during the label process?

Is it possible to have any tape from the Full pool an available drive in the autoloader so that two jobs can be run simultaneously?

Do two SD daemons need to be running?

** bareos-sd.d/server-sd.conf**

```
storage {
  Name = server-sd
  Maximum Concurrent Jobs = 20
  # Plugin Directory = /usr/lib/bareos/plugins
  # Plugin Names = ""
}
```

** bareos-sd.d/autochanger/autochanger-0.conf **

```
Autochanger {
  Name = "FlexStor_II"
  Changer Device = /dev/tape/by-id/scsi-1BDT_FlexStor_II_xxxxxxxxxxx_LL0 
  Device = ULTRIUM-HH7-0
  Device = ULTRIUM-HH7-1
  Changer Command = "/usr/lib/bareos/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"
}
```

** less bareos-sd.d/device/ULTRIUM-HH7-0.conf **

```
Device {
    Name = "ULTRIUM-HH7-0"
    DeviceType = tape
    DriveIndex = 0
    ArchiveDevice = /dev/tape/by-id/scsi-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx001-nst
    MediaType = LTO-7
    AutoChanger = yes                       # default: no
    AutomaticMount = yes                    # default: no
    MaximumFileSize = 500GB                  # default: 1000000000 (1GB)
    AlwaysOpen = yes
    Autoselect = yes
    RemovableMedia = yes
}
```

** bareos-sd.d/device/ULTRIUM-HH7-1.conf **

```
Device {
    Name = "ULTRIUM-HH7-1"
    DeviceType = tape
    DriveIndex = 1
    ArchiveDevice = /dev/tape/by-id/scsi-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx004-nst
    MediaType = LTO-7
    AutoChanger = yes                       # default: no
    AutomaticMount = yes                    # default: no
    MaximumFileSize = 500GB                  # default: 1000000000 (1GB)
    AlwaysOpen = yes
    Autoselect = yes
    RemovableMedia = yes
}
```

** bareos-dir.d/storage/Tape.conf **

```
Storage {
  Name = Tape
  Address = server                # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here (do not use "localhost" here).
  Password = "e9cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxg"
  Device = FlexStor_II 
  Media Type = LTO-7
  Autochanger = yes
}
```

Comment: Bounty added ...

Comment: it is easy to run into a limitation in the reservation-code. What does "status dir" tell you? What is the job waiting for?

Comment: @AndreasRogge Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I left that job. So it's a dead issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the BareOS documentation](http://doc.bareos.org/master/html/bareos-manual-main-reference.html#x1-24600019.3):

> As a default, Bareos jobs will prefer to write to a Volume that is
>   already mounted. If you have a multiple drive autochanger and you want
>   Bareos to write to more than one Volume in the same Pool at the same
>   time, you will need to set **Prefer Mounted Volumes Dir Job = no**. This
>   will cause the Storage daemon to maximize the use of drives.

Comment: Hi @wazoox. Thanks for the response. I had tried that, but could never get it to kick on the second drive. Have you done this yourself? Maybe I need some additional pointers?